# Is it correct to say, "The king gifted him with a generous amount of gold, horses and chariots"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, word-usage, uncountable-nouns

Is it correct to say...

> The king gifted him with a generous amount of gold, horses and chariots

Not sure whether 'amount' can be used here, since 'horses' and 'chariots' are listed with an uncountable noun like 'gold'.

As I understand, 'gold' here is used in the uncountable form. Not gold coins, for example.

Comment: It's ambiguous whether "a generous amount of" modifies horses and chariots as well gold. Regardless, you do occasionally see amount with countable nouns. Anyway, this is one of several questions on the theme and seems to be a duplicate...

Comment: After reading the answer of question you had referred to, I have rephrased my sentence to: "The king gifted him with gold, horses and chariots, all in generous amounts". Hope it is now correctly formed with the ambiguity removed.

Comment: Is active 'gift X with Y' idiomatic?

Comment: Clicked this expecting the Q to be about the verb, not the object.